# SharePoint 2016 Cannot create any service - Error TimedOut

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, spservices, 2016

I have Two Servers one for SharePoint 2016 Farm and the other for SQL Database.
One of the users called me and told me that the Search is not working! when I checked the service its started but when I checked Search Topology its EMPTY!

so I start troubleshooting with no success! i decided to delete the service and recreate it again! I couldn't delete it from central administration but I managed by **STSADM.EXE**. when I tried to recreate the service, it keep in process for long time and ending with error **TIME OUT**

I tried to create another service like access service to check. got the same result! I got the same from both sides Central Administration and Powershell!

Also, tried to recreate services from **CONFIGURATION WIZARD**. got the same result!

**Note**: tried to created subsite in the site collection which has its own content database and created successfully with no errors.

**correlation ID errors**

[image]

[image]

**Other Errors got from log**

[image]

**what I did for troubleshooting**

- restart both servers
- cleared SPTimer configuration cache
- Cleared History Jobs
- Repair SharePoint product
- installed sharepoint configuration in powershell "**PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures**"
- checked all service, service application pools, database content by the Powershell and all good!

EDITED:

tried to give user profile service pool admin account in configure service accounts page. when i clicked ok it kept loading for half an hour and got the same error after.

[image]
none of above troubleshooting solve my problem! I am not sure is it run time fault or Noderunner!! 
Please I need help.
Thanks

Comment: do you have any antivirus or any other auditing software installed on the servers, which may blocking these actions.